# Почему не работает media запрос

Tags: css, вёрстка, media-queries

```
@media screen and(max-width: 420px){
    .header-container{
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .main-menu{
        display: none;
    }
    .main-menu li{
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .main-menu a{
        display: block;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    .toggle-button{
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #000;
    }
}
```

Comment: после `and` - пробел.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что сам media запрос написан с ошибкой. 
После слова *and* нужно поставить пробел.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px){ /* стили */ }
```

Comment: И правда, спасибо

Comment: не за что, обращайтесь :)